# XMLHttpRequest not working for IE 11 for file download

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

var formdata = new FormData();

```
    var xhr = null;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined"){
        try {

            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0");
        }
        catch(e){
            try {

                xhr = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try {

                    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e){

                    xhr = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.open("GET",url, true); ///fileUploadTester/FileUploader

    xhr.send(formdata);


    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onload = function(e) {


        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
        {

            var urlIE = URL;
            window.location = urlIE;
        }
        else
        {
            window.location = this.responseURL;
        }
    };
}
```

The above code is from my javaScript method when i call that method my requirement is to download file for user.
In java i have a method to generate file and add it to response

For other browsers i am able to call the method and get response back but for IE 11 i am not able to do. 
Any Solution for this or any errors in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer The way i was getting browser name was wrong.
Once i got correct browser name using javascript it stated working

Answer (score 0):

FormData() is not supported by ie11.u can build the formdata string by yourself.

```
function sendData(data) {
  console.log('Sending data');

  const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

  const urlEncodedDataPairs = [];

  // Turn the data object into an array of URL-encoded key/value pairs.
  for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    urlEncodedDataPairs.push(`${encodeURIComponent(name)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`);
  }

  // Combine the pairs into a single string and replace all %-encoded spaces to
  // the '+' character; matches the behavior of browser form submissions.
  const urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');

  // Define what happens on successful data submission
  XHR.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
  });

  // Define what happens in case of an error
  XHR.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
    alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
  });

  // Set up our request
  XHR.open('POST', 'https://example.com/cors.php');

  // Add the required HTTP header for form data POST requests
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  // Finally, send our data.
  XHR.send(urlEncodedData);
}
```

check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#gaining_control_of_the_global_interface) for more